# How to refer to a ParseObject before it has been issues an ObjectId (saved)?

Tags: android, parse-platform

A ParseObject only get's it's `ObjectId` once it's been saved. **If I were offline at the time of creation and couldn't save the object, how can I refer to it whilst still being offline?**

> For instance how do I set a comment's postId when I don't yet know the
>   post's Id?

I was considering making a separate attribute called `TempId` in my extended `ParseObject`, which I can put an exclusively locally known Id that it can refer to until it has a proper Object Id, but is this the best choice I have?

The following concern me with this:

1. Double Handling
2. Maintaining all the callbacks necessary to make sure I update the correct object in the correct order.

Thanks!

Comment: In the case that concerns you, the post has not yet been saved. If you dive into their local datastore, it supports creating and saving both post and comment prior to being saved online using `saveEventually()`. Actually you can create both and only save the comment, which then will save the post recursively as it is referred as pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my rule of thumb: think objects, not objectIDs.

```
var post = // ... this is a real object, not an id. it can be new
var comment = // ... this is a real object, not an id.  it can be new

// posts might have many comments by keeping an array of pointers called "comments"
post.add("comments", comment);

// or posts might have many comments by keeping a relation called "comments"
post.relation("comments").add(comment);
```

After doing this, the parent side of the relationship can be saved, and the unsaved children will be saved, too:

```
post.save().then(function(savedPost) {
    // savedPost now has savedPost.id, but who cares?
    // if comments is an array of pointers:
    // savedPost.get("comments") now has comments with ids, but again, we don't need them.

    // if comments is a relation:
    return savedPost.get("comments").query.find();
}).then(function(comments) {
    // comments is an array of objects with ids, but again, if I find
    // myself needing those ids, its a clue that my design is weak
});
```