# Getting objectid of a parse object related to the list item

Tags: android, listview, parse-platform

I have a list view that retrieves data from parse.com. I have added a onitemlongclicllstener to delete the list item that is long pressed from the list and even from the parse database. I know how to remove from list but don't know how to from the parse database. 
Every listitem has a unique object id related to it. 
If we want to delete from parse database this is how we do it according to the parse documentation

```
ParseObject.createWithoutData("invFriend", "efgh").deleteEventually();
```

Where my friend is the class name and efgh is the object id related to the list item to be deleted

This works if we know the object id

But what if we don't know the object id of the list item what the user has long pressed
How to pass in the object id parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can find the object id for each list item like this

```
channelList.get(i).getObjectId()
```

Where channelList is the parse object list.